# Django. Вывод и добавление продукции в табличном виде

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Пишу простенькую crm для проектов на Django. В каждом проекте есть товары которые менеджер может добавить.
Есть три модели: Project, OrderItem, Product.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_index=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_index=True, verbose_name="Название проекта")

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    project= models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='orderitems', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Продукт")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, verbose_name="Количество")
```

Мне необходимо вывести форму с добавлением проекта и продуктов в него. 
Если я использую:

```py
OrderItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Project, OrderItem, form = OrderForm, )
```

То продукты выводятся Select-ами из заказов. 
Я хочу выводить весь список продуктов рядом количество продукта в заказе. 
И после нажатия кнопки сохранить продукты с не нулевым количеством добавлялись/обновлялись в orderitem_set к проекту. 
Вывод я сделать могу: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как написать мне сохранение в orderitem_set? 
Есть ли готовые решения для такого вывода?